# How to apply a function on each item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sitemap with about 21 urls on it and each of those urls contains about 2000 more urls. I'm trying to write something that will allow me to parse each of the original 21 urls and grab their containing 2000 urls then append it to a list.

I've been bashing my head against a wall for a few days now trying to get this to work, but it keeps returning a list of 'None'. I've only been working with python for about a 3 weeks now, so I might be missing something really obvious. Any help would be great!

```
storage = []
storage1 = []

for x in range(21):
url = 'first part of the url' + str(x) + '.xml'
storage.append(url)

def parser(any):
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(any))
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in range(len(storage)):
        x = (root[i][0]).text
        storage1.append(x)

storage2 = [parser(x) for x in storage]
```

I also tried using a while loop with a counter, but it always stopped after the first 2000 urls.

Comment: Your method should also return something. Otherwise storage2 will be empty :o

Comment: You can also use the `map` function. `storage2 = map(parser, storage)`

Answer (score 1):

`parser()` never `return`s anything, so it defaults to returning `None`, hence why `storage2` contains a list of `None`s. Perhaps you want to look at what's in `storage1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare a return for a function in python, it automatically returns `None`. Inside `parser` you're adding elements to `storage1`, but aren't returning anything. I would give this a shot instead.

```
storage = []

for x in range(21):
    url = 'first part of the url' + str(x) + '.xml'
    storage.append(url)

def parser(any):
    storage1 = []
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(any))
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in range(len(storage)):
        x = (root[i][0]).text
        storage1.append(x)
    return storage1

storage2 = [parser(x) for x in storage]
```

**EDIT:** As Amber said, you should also see that all your elements were actually being stored in `storage1`.

Comment: Yes, the use of a local list is excellent. The original poster should realize that storage2 is now a list of lists, since each call to parser returns a list. It should be noted that len(storage) should be len(root), since the iteration in parser is over the children of the root.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have two stages in your program:

1. You generate initial list of the 21 URLs
2. You fetch the page at each of those URLs, and extract additional URLs from the page.

Your first step could look like this:

```
initial_urls = [('http://...%s...' % x) for x in range(21)]
```

Then, to populate the large list of URLs from the pages, you could do something like this:

```
big_list = []

def extract_urls(source):
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(any))
    for link in get_links(tree):
        big_list.append(link.attrib['href'])

def get_links(tree):
    ... - define the logic for link extraction here

for url in initial_urls:
    extract_urls(url)

print big_list
```

Note that you'll have to write the procedure that extracts the links from the document yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 'any' in first line of extract_urls should be 'source'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return storage1 in the parser function

```
def parser(any):
    tree = ET.parse(urlopen(any))
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in range(len(storage)):
        x = (root[i][0]).text
        storage1.append(x)
    return storage1
```

I think this is what you want.